How to Create a Transparent Inner Border Effect in Flutter?
I'm trying to create an inner border effect in Flutter that appears transparent, allowing the background image inside the widget to be visible through the border area, similar to the effect shown in the image below.
The inner border should appear just inside the widget’s edges, and it needs to have a transparent or semi-transparent look.

How can I achieve this transparent inner border effect in Flutter?
Any ideas or code suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

The border is always inner. So you can just add an opaque white border that fades out the background color like so:
Container(
  width: 200,
  height: 200,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    color: Colors.green,
    border: Border.all(
      color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.5),
      width: 4,
    ),
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
  ),
),

Result:


i want the background image inside the widget to be visible through the border area not a constant green color

@AkhilGeorge so use DecoratedBox with border you need and child: Image(...)

@pskink It works
